# PHP PDO error when executing numeric array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I'm making a script that adds an order to a database. When inserting (many many fields I can't do this simply by querying the database 50 times every time a user visits the page so it has to go into one single query.

I made a script that dynamically adds the selected amount of records that are linked to the amount of data given in an array.

But whenever I try to execute the query it gives me an error that my syntax is not correct.

**My code:**

```
private function addOrderDetails($products, $orderID) {
    # Base of the query (will be the end result)
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `Database`.`orderDetails` (
        `amount`, 
        `price`, 
        `tax`, 
        `product_id`, 
        `order_id`
    ) VALUES (:?, :?, :?, :?, :?)';

    # Added to the query if there are more than 1 products
    $queryExtension = ', (:?, :?, :?, :?, :?)';
    $queryPayload   = array();

    # Loop through all products and add them to the query payload
    foreach ($products as $counter => $productArray) {
        # Add all values individually
        foreach ($productArray as $value) {
            array_push($queryPayload, $value);
        }

        # Add the orderID at the end and extend the query (if the key is more than 0)
        array_push($queryPayload, $orderID);
        if ($counter > 0) $query .= $queryExtension;
    }

    # Execute the array
    $query  = $this->DB->prepare($query);
    $query->execute($queryPayload);        # Error on this exact line, if I put an exit; here it throws no error.
}
```

**My array with data:**

```
array(
    array(
        'amount'    => 50,
        'price'     => 10,
        'tax'       => 2,
        'productID' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'amount'    => 27,
        'price'     => 19,
        'tax'       => 6,
        'productID' => 15
    ),
    array(
        'amount'    => 492,
        'price'     => 2300,
        'tax'       => 4.5,
        'productID' => 50
    )
);
```

**My error:**

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':'50', :'10', :'2', :'5', :'42'), (:'27', :'19', :'6', :'15', :'42'), (:'492', :' at line 7' in (webroot)
Stack trace:
#0 (webroot): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 (webroot): Database->addOrderDetails(Array, '42')
#2 (webroot): Database->addOrder(1, '1', Array)
#3 {main}
```

Comment: loose the colons. Non-named placeholders are `?`, not `:?`. You can also add elements to an array using `$array[] = 'add this';`. It's shorter than using `array_push`, and saves a function call

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Oh wow that was just plain stupid of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, named placeholders start with a colon. You don't seem to be using named placeholders, and so a regular question mark will do. IE replace `:?` with `?`.

That said, you seem to be missing out on the best part of using prepared statements: you can re-use the prepared query with different values. You are adding, and adding on to the query string, when simply there is no need:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `Database`.`orderDetails` (
        `amount`, 
        `price`, 
        `tax`, 
        `product_id`, 
        `order_id`
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$pdo->beginTransaction();//best use transactions here, though
foreach ($products as $counter => $productArray)
{
    $bind = array_values($productArray);//though strictly speaking, this isn't required
    $stmt->execute($bind);//add this array
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
$pdo->commit();
```

A prepared statement is a pre-compiled, pre-optimized query, that just needs the input (ie the values to insert) in order to be executed. If a query can be compiled and optimized ahead of time, why wouldn't it be possible to use the same resource more than once? As you can see from the code above: you *can* re-use the statement, all you have to do (it's not *strictly* required, but it is best you do it), is to notify PDO (and the DB) each time you've finished running the statement. `PDOStatement::closeCursor` does this for you.

Because you're trying to insert the data in one query, I suggested using a transaction. This way, if one of the queries fails, an exception can be thrown, and you can undo all of the queries you've run thusfar:

```
try
{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    //same code as above
    $pdo->commit();//save changes
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{//something went wrong
    $pdo->rollBack();//undo changes
}
```